# grep: print both matches

Tags: awk, grep

the following command returns only matches from file2.

```
grep -f file1 file2
```

How is it possible to print match line from the first file (file1) following the second match from file2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{res[$0]; next}
{
    found = 0
    for (re in res) {
        if ($0 ~ re) {
            print "found:", re
            found = 1
        }
    }
}
found
' file1 file2
```

Comment: thanks a lot. could you please tell me how to print matches in one line (tab separated)?

Comment: @Ed Morton I am also interested in partial matching lines but it seems your code gives only complete matches, am I correct? for this reason I used grep.

Comment: @MaryamSani no, you're wrong. try it and let us know of any specific issues, with examples.